# Curious to mscorlib reference

Tags: .net, silverlight, frameworks, mscorlib

I am curious as to the `mscorlib` reference in different project templates.

When I create a WPF project, I cannot find the `mscorlib` file in the reference folder. I think it is referenced by default.

When I create a Silverlight project, I can find it in the folder. It links to the Silverlight framework. Then I tried to delete it and of course it cannot be compiled. Then I tried to re-add this assembly to the reference again; it cannot be added and cannot be compiled anymore. It's weird.

When I create a MonoDroid project, I can still find the `mscorlib` reference. But after I deleted this reference, the project still can be compiled; but I'm not sure if it runs fine.

Does anyone knows what causes this behavior?

Thanks,
Howard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue that will not be able to fix for VS2010. The workaround is to edit the project file and manually re-add the reference.

Answer (score 8):

Just so someone does not have to google it.  I was missing the mscorlib and found the exact way CuiPengFei suggested to do this in the project file, here:[Microsoft Connect Feedback](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/519214/silverlight-4-application-project-remove-reference-to-mscorlib-or-system-core-and-they-cant-be-readded)
in the workaround which was posted by James Wightman on 12/9/2009 at 2:52 AM below:

> As I said in the bug report, one
>   workaround is to manually add the
>   reference back into the project
>   manually by editing the csproj file
>   using (for example) notepad:
>
> Find this section in the csproj file -
>   obviously if you have
>   different/additional references that's
>   what you're looking for:
>
> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>  <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
>  <Reference Include="system" />
>  <Reference Include="System.Net" />
>  <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
>  <Reference Include="System.Windows.Browser" />
> </ItemGroup>
> ```
>
> Add a line for each of the missing
>   references - in this case, mscorlib
>   and System.Core - and your csproj file
>   should now look something like this:
>
> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>  <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
>  <Reference Include="System.Core" />
>  <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
>  <Reference Include="system" />
>  <Reference Include="System.Net" />
>  <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
>  <Reference Include="System.Windows.Browser" />
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer here. I would also like to add that after including the reference you may need to restart Visual Studio before it will start working