# C#: SerializableAttribute could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, .net-core

I am trying to use the **[Serializable]** attribute in a C# class library project (latest .NET version), but it is **not recognised**.

As far as I could search, Serializable it something that belongs in <s>System.Runtime.Serialization</s> System, but I have used it and it still doesn't work.

I am using it in other projects (Unity), but it doesn't work here. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Model{
    [Serializable]
    public struct GameSettings{
        public int Players;
    }
}
```

[image: The exact error I am getting]

Thank you in advance

Edit: format
Edit2: screenshot of the error

Comment: What is your environment?  .Net 4.5?  .Net core?  Unity3d?  Something else?

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: @dbc I am using the latest .NET version for a .NETCoreApp v1.1

Comment: @dbc The [Serializable] attribute does work in Unity, but that is a standalone class library (as I mentioned above)

Comment: Have you disabled the core libraries in your project (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902373/34092 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/11560352/34092 )?

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'? Do you mean 'it doesn't compile' or something else? If something else, talk us through what that looks like.

Comment: This is the error I am getting. [link](http://prntscr.com/finarm)
I'm checking out the linked questions now

Comment: @mjwills I checked the links you have provided and no; I have not done anything to remove mscorelib from the references

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of \[Serializable\] in .NET Core ? (Conversion Projects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199049/what-is-the-equivalent-of-serializable-in-net-core-conversion-projects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://apisof.net/catalog/System.SerializableAttribute shows that `[Serializable]` is defined in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters` package for .NET Core 1.0 and 1.1 and .NET Standard 1.6.  It then moved to System.Runtime for .NET Core 2.0 and the `netstandard` monolith for .NET Standard 2.0.

If you just care about being able to compile shared code, you could try adding the package reference.  But [What is the equivalent of [Serializable] in .NET Core ? (Conversion Projects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199049/what-is-the-equivalent-of-serializable-in-net-core-conversion-projects) has already answered that the binary serializer isn't in .NET Core 1.x (unsure about its 2.0 status... but since 2.0 is in preview you could always try it out).

Answer (score 3):

This attribute lives in `System`, not in `System.Runtime.Serialization`:

```
namespace System
{
  /// <summary>Indicates that a class can be serialized. This class cannot be inherited.</summary>
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Delegate, Inherited = false)]
  [ComVisible(true)]
  public sealed class SerializableAttribute : Attribute
  {
      //...
  }
}
```

Are you sure you have referenced `mscorlib.dll`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672047/curious-to-mscorlib-reference) might be interessting for you.

Comment: As you can see System is already being used. 
I did try to explicitly add mscorlib.dll in the dependencies but that created even more errors.

Comment: The answer from Christian seems correct for Unity. At least, it worked for me after freshly installing Unity 2018.3.8f1 and the corresponding VisualStudio package.

Comment: Yeah, the question later changed into a .net core question.